# Pool Recycling error 2 sprites collides at the same time to a sprite

Tags: java, android, andengine

I have a shooting game where, you shoot two bullets at the opposite direction, so happens that if an enemy gets close to the starting point of the bullet(enemy is in the area of the bullet starting point) a error happens,

here is my code:

```
if((_target.collidesWith(bullet))){

                    resourcesManager.enemyPool.recyclePoolItem(_target);
                    targets.remove();
                    score=score+1;

                }
                if((_target.collidesWith(bullet2))){
                    resourcesManager.enemyPool.recyclePoolItem(_target);
                    targets.remove();
                    score=score+1;
                    break;
                }
```

Error Log:

```
09-30 09:47:23.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1167): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.www.tangent
09-30 09:47:23.550: I/Process(1167): Sending signal. PID: 1167 SIG: 9
09-30 09:47:23.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1167): FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
09-30 09:47:23.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1167): java.lang.IllegalStateException
09-30 09:47:23.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at java.util.LinkedList$LinkIterator.remove(LinkedList.java:164)
09-30 09:47:23.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at com.www.scene.WeaponSelectScene$1.onUpdate(WeaponSelectScene.java:318)
09-30 09:47:23.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at org.andengine.engine.handler.UpdateHandlerList.onUpdate(UpdateHandlerList.java:47)
09-30 09:47:23.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedUpdate(Entity.java:1395)
09-30 09:47:23.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onManagedUpdate(Scene.java:284)
09-30 09:47:23.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onUpdate(Entity.java:1167)
09-30 09:47:23.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onManagedUpdate(Scene.java:288)
09-30 09:47:23.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onUpdate(Entity.java:1167)
09-30 09:47:23.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdateScene(Engine.java:591)
09-30 09:47:23.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdate(Engine.java:586)
09-30 09:47:23.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at org.andengine.engine.LimitedFPSEngine.onUpdate(LimitedFPSEngine.java:56)
09-30 09:47:23.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:548)
09-30 09:47:23.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:820)
09-30 09:47:23.570: I/BstWindowOrientationListener(521): getCurrentRotation(0)
09-30 09:47:23.570: I/ActivityManager(521): Process com.www.tangent (pid 1167) has died.
09-30 09:47:23.570: I/WindowManager(521): WIN DEATH: Window{b4846b48 SurfaceView paused=false}
09-30 09:47:23.590: E/InputDispatcher(521): channel 'b472fa40 com.www.tangent/com.www.tangent.GameActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
09-30 09:47:23.590: E/InputDispatcher(521): channel 'b472fa40 com.www.tangent/com.www.tangent.GameActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
09-30 09:47:23.590: I/WindowManager(521): WIN DEATH: Window{b472fa40 com.www.tangent/com.www.tangent.GameActivity paused=false}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem, and your problem with no answer made me found mine.

Indeed, here you have concurrent deletion into your recyclePoolItem, because in one frame, you delete two times the same object (occurs when your _target collides with two objects). To correct this simply write your code with "else if" instead of just "if" under the "if" statement:

```
if((_target.collidesWith(bullet))){
    resourcesManager.enemyPool.recyclePoolItem(_target);
    targets.remove();
    score=score+1;
} else if((_target.collidesWith(bullet2))){
    resourcesManager.enemyPool.recyclePoolItem(_target);
    targets.remove();
    score=score+1;
}
```